# Local Group Policy not updating. RSOP and GPResult show stale data

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

This issue exists on a Windows 7 Pro x64 machine (Dell Inspiron E6420). I am trying to adjust a setting using `gpedit.msc`, but the change never seems to take effect. By that, I mean the setting that is changed never shows up in `rsop` or `gpresult`.

The exact setting is called `Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings` which is currently reported as `Enabled` in RSOP/gpresult.

Even if I set this to `not configured` or `disabled` using `gpedit.msc`, the change never shows in a `gpresult` query. Not even after a `gpupdate` or reboot.

However it **will** show the updated setting in `gpedit` (not that it makes a difference at that point if it can't apply).

## Error messages

A few points of concern:

1. This error happens when running `gpupdate`:

   > Updating Policy... User Policy update has completed successfully. Computer Policy update has completed successfully.
   >   The following
   >   warnings were encountered during computer policy processing:
   >   Windows
   >   failed to apply the Scripts settings. Scripts settings might have its
   >   own log file. Please click on the "More information" link.
   >   For more
   >   detailed information, review the event log or run GPRESULT /H
   >   GPReport.html from the command line to access information about Group
   >   Policy results.
2. When running an `RSOP` or `GPresult`, there is a yellow exclamation point on the `Computer Configuration` section.
3. Under `Component Status`, these two errors are showing, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to clear them:

   > Component Status  Component Name Status Last Process Time  Group
   >   Policy Infrastructure Success 6/14/2013 3:46:11 PM  Internet Explorer
   >   Zonemapping Success (no data) 2/6/2013 10:29:33 AM  Registry Failed
   >   6/14/2013 3:46:11 PM  Registry failed due to the error listed below.
   >
   > Unspecified error
   >
   > Additional information may have been logged. Review the Policy Events
   >   tab in the console or the application event log for events between
   >   6/14/2013 3:46:10 PM and 6/14/2013 3:46:11 PM.
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Scripts Failed 6/14/2013 3:46:11 PM  Scripts failed due to the error
   >   listed below.
   >
   > Access is denied.
   >
   > Additional information may have been logged. Review the Policy Events
   >   tab in the console or the application event log for events between
   >   6/14/2013 3:46:11 PM and 6/14/2013 3:46:11 PM.
   >
   > Security Success 6/14/2013 3:46:11 PM

## Things that didn't work

So far I've tried:

1. Resetting local group policy:
   `secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose`
2. Another method I found to try and reset local group policy:
   Deleted `c:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy` and forced a `gpupdate`
3. Copying group policy settings from a known working computer with similar config:
   Copied `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy`
4. Deleting Registry key, but after reboot it just comes right back:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions\DenyUnspecified`

Anyone have any other ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If the machine on a domain? Perhaps domain policies are overriding your local policies.   What does the "Origin" column in RSOP.msc state for that specific policy?

Comment: For something this advanced I would recommend moving your question to http://ServerFault.com, You can flag your own question to be moved or delete this question here and re-ask it there. Please do not post the same question in both places at the same time.

Comment: @techie007 The machine is on a domain, however there are no conflicting policies that should be causing this issue. The origin for this specific policy shows Local Group Policy.

Answer (score 3):

## Test file share connectivity and permissions

Test command at workstation:

```
nslookup %USERDNSDOMAIN%

net view %USERDNSDOMAIN%

cd \\%USERDNSDOMAIN%\SYSVOL\%USERDNSDOMAIN%\
```

and check file permissions in folders: `Policies` and `scripts`

## Check other ports' connectivity

open and check port at domain infrastructure

Instructions here: [Active Directory Firewall Ports - Let's Try To Make This Simple](http://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2011/11/01/active-directory-firewall-ports-let-s-try-to-make-this-simple/)

## Nuke local registry key

delete registry key:

```
reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies /f
reg delete HKCU\Software\Policies /f
```

## Nuke local folder

delete folder:

```
RD /S /Q %windir%\System32\GroupPolicy
```